# Como puedo hacer para que solo el checkbox que sea igual se muestre como disabled y los demas que no sea igual se muestren

Tags: vue.js

Los valores de array item1 los estoy recorriendo por medio de un v-for y se visualizan por medio de un checkbox  lo que deseo es que si alguno de los valores del item1 llegan hacer igual a los de los valores del item2 esos valor que sean iguales se me liste como un checkbox disable (no se pueda seleccionar ) y los demas valores que no son iguales a los del item2 se listen como checkbox normal. para poder seleccionarlos y poder guardar

````
  <ul v-for="(r, index) in item1" :key="index">
    <input
      v-model="colorCantidad"
      :disabled="ver"
      type="checkbox"
      :name="r"
      :id="r"
    />
  </ul>
  <p>Result = {{ item2 }}</p>
  <button @click="myFunction()">Click Me</button>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      item1: [12, 10, 9, 5, 6, 4],
      item2: [12, 9, 4],
      result: "",
      ver: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    myFunction: function () {},
  },
  computed: {
    colorCantidad() {
      this.item1.forEach((element) => {
        console.log(element);
        if (element === this.item2) {
          return (this.ver = true);
        } else {
          return (this.ver = false);
        }
      });
    },
  },
};
</script>```
````

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: @Comunidad dale gracias

Answer (score 0):

Bueno, tendría que usar la propiedad computada en su `v-for`, debido a que esta retornaría los valores repetidos en los arrays para luego hacer dinámico el disabled de los checks. Entonces, una posible solución:

```
<template>
  <div >
   <ul v-for="(state, i) in stateCheck" :key="i">
    <input
      :disabled="state"
      type="checkbox"
    />
  </ul>
   <!-- estado de cada checkbox -->
  {{stateCheck}}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  data: ()=>({
    item1: [12, 10, 9, 5, 6, 4],
    item2: [12, 9, 4],
  }),
  computed:{
    stateCheck(){
      return this.item1.map(rep=> this.item2.includes(rep))
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

`Includes`:  *Determina si una matriz incluye un determinado elemento, devuelve true o false según corresponda.*

`map`: *Crea un nuevo array con los resultados de la llamada a la función indicada aplicados a cada uno de sus elementos.*

La propiedad computada `stateCheck` obtendrá el valor booleano de los números repetidos entre arrays item1 e item2 para luego ser iterado y usar sus índices en **true** para inhabilitar los checkboks y viceversa.

Comment: gracias por la ayuda

Comment: @JuanEsteban Si fue solución no olvide marcar la  respuesta, como útil, saludos